# Frontier template

Tags: frontier

I would like to build a frontier based node. However I am confused about what to start with

should I generate my template using the script `./node-template-release.sh` as mentioned in  https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/template

(This process failed to build!)

Or should I directly use this template
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template

Comment: What error did you encounter?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier this one https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/issues/737#issuecomment-1214426976

Comment: I believe this is still relevant: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3760/29

Answer (score 2):

A great way to start with the Frontier node is the [Substrate tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/integrate-with-tools/access-evm-accounts/) and it uses the template from the substrate developer hub. Verified today that it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a great way to start is probably to watch this subzero video and then maybe try and follow along and do it yourself locally over a weekend learning as you go:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9KfvhoqLJ4